# python: importing libpci raises SyntaxError

Tags: python, python-2.7

I just installed libpci on my machine:

```
$ pip2.7 install libpci
```

And tried to run this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7
import libpci

print('hello libpci')
```

but this raises the following syntax error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 2, in <module>
    import libpci
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/libpci/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from libpci.wrapper import LibPCI
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/libpci/wrapper.py", line 26, in <module>
    from libpci._functions import pci_alloc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/libpci/_functions.py", line 39
    def pci_alloc() -> ctypes.POINTER(pci_access):
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How is it possible to have SyntaxError raised in libpci?
Is it because I am missing some dependencies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`libpci` project](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/libpci) requires Python 3.4 or newer. From the project tags:

> ```
> Categories
> [...]
> Programming Language :: Python :: 3
> Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4
> ```

The syntax error is thrown because the project uses [annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/), a Python 3 feature, to configure the `ctypes` layer, see the [`_ctypes_metadata()` function](https://github.com/zyga/libpci/blob/master/libpci/_native.py#L54).